# Using R tidyverse to save conditional mean mean as an object

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean of a continuous variable if the corresponding binary variable is 1. I used

```
  dataset %>% 
    group_by(binary) %>% 
    summarise(continuos_mean = mean(continuous, na.rm = TRUE))
```

but that gives me a tibble and not one value/the mean that I can't then save as an object. How can I get one value?

Comment: Can you add some example data and also check your code example, I'm not sure why you'd have `dataset %>%  \`dataset %>%`

Comment: Just an FYI - it looks like `continuos_mean` might be a typo. Should this be `continuous_mean`? I've had issues like this slip my up later in the analysis pipeline *a lot*

Answer (score 2):

`filter` for `binary == 1` followed by `pull` should get you to a single value.

```
dataset %>% 
  group_by(binary) %>% 
  summarise(continuos_mean = mean(continuous, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(binary == 1) %>%
  pull(continuos_mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
dataset <- data.frame(binary = c(1, 0, 1, 0), continuous = c(1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 3.2))
dataset

#  binary continuous
#1      1        1.2
#2      0        2.3
#3      1        3.4
#4      0        3.2

result <- mean(dataset$continuous[dataset$binary == 1], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2.3
```

If you want `tidyverse` methods you can use either of these.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  filter(binary == 1) %>%
  summarise(continuos_mean = mean(continuous, na.rm = TRUE))

#OR

dataset %>%
  summarise(continuos_mean = mean(continuous[binary == 1], na.rm = TRUE))
```